# executing a script via ssh, not real output

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell-script

I am executing a script via ssh in this way:

```
 ssh user@host 'bash -s' < ./script.sh
```

the problem is that, sometimes, the output that I get is not correct, the lines are mixed.

In my case the script executes notmuch new, the normal output is something like:

```
...
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Processed 93 total files in almost no time.
No new mail.
```

but sometimes the output is something like:

```
...
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Processed 93 total files in almost no time.
No new mail.
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
Note: Ignoring non-mail file: foobar
```

and for sure this is not the real output from `notmuch new`, the command ends with `No new mail` but it's like it gets the output via ssh not line by line.

Why this happen?

Comment: My guess: some of the output is to stdout, some other output is to stderr. If going non interactive, buffering might differ, thus changing the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffering. If we search the source code for `notmuch`

```
$ find . -name \*.c -exec grep 'Ignoring non-mail file' {} +
./notmuch-new.c:    fprintf (stderr, "Note: Ignoring non-mail file: %s\n", filename);
$ find . -name \*.c -exec grep 'No new mail' {} +
./notmuch-new.c:    printf ("No new mail.");
$
```

Some of those messages use standard error (which is unbuffered by default) and some use standard out (which is line- or block-buffered by default, depending on whether standard out is to a terminal or to a file). This behavior comes from the standard C library, see [`setvbuf(3)`](http://man.openbsd.org/setvbuf) for details. Thus `stderr` messages get written immediately, while the `printf` calls to `stdout` will show up...well, it depends.

Buffering is typically configured by each application individually, though maybe can be monkeyed around with using utilities such as `stdbuf` (though some consider the `LD_PRELOAD` tricks used by `stdbuf` to be quite horrible...).

The difference is easy to reproduce locally; for example writing to the terminal (line-based buffering for `stdout`):

```
$ perl -E 'for (1..4) { say "out"; warn "err\n" }'
out
err
out
err
out
err
out
err
$
```

while instead if that exact same code is instead redirected to a file (block-based buffering for `stdout`):

```
$ perl -E 'for (1..4) { say "out"; warn "err\n" }' >x 2>&1
$ cat x
err
err
err
err
out
out
out
out
$
```

`ssh` adds an additional layer of complication, as one may also have to figure out how it is collecting, buffering, and sending bytes, in addition to `notmuch` and then what `ssh` is wired up to on the client system...

Comment: I understand your point but why this behavior is shown only executing the command remotely?

Comment: it's easy to show a problem locally, in addition to the complications that `ssh` adds.

Comment: P.S. things can go even worse if you try concurrent reads/writes to the same socket - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364396/concurrently-reading-writing-to-the-same-unix-socket/364438 - as in possible data corruption